# Make multiple divs position fixed after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is have multiple images stick to the top of my page, overlapping eachother, once they're scrolled past. A very good example is [this one](http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/).

What I have right now are 3 div's wich through a JS script are always the users screenheight/width. Within these divs are the images.

```
<div id="part1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <img src="img/part1.png"> 
        </div><!-- .twelve columns -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- part1 -->

<div id="part2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <img src="img/part2.png"> 
        </div><!-- .twelve columns -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- part2 -->

<div id="part3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <img src="img/part3.png"> 
        </div><!-- .twelve columns -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- part3 -->

#part1, #part2, #part3 { width:100%; height:100%; }
#part1 { z-index:1; }
#part2 { z-index:2; }
#part3 { z-index:3; }
.stick { position:fixed; top:0; margin:0 auto; }
```

I've been playing around with the most found functions such as this one:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#part1_anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#part1').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#part1').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

But it doesn't give me the desired result, plus doesn't allow me to define multiple divs to this function. I'm running out of ideas, and any help is really appreciated.

Comment: create demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem with this brilliant script

[Stickyscroll](https://github.com/rickharris/StickyScroll)